# how to change permission of /proc/self/pagemap file.?

Tags: linux, permissions, operating-system

I want to change the pagemap file permission to 755 or 744 using sudo chmod. But the command is throwing error saying operation not permitted. The motivation is to allow a user read the pagemap file (of its own) without giving sudo access.

When the user have sudo access it is working, he allowed to read pagemap file. But I want to prevent the user to have sudo access, but should allow him to read this pagemap file alone. Please help me how can I do this.??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

/proc/self/pagemap     has usually access mode of 400  (-r--------)

This means that the user is allowed to read pagemap of its own without sudo.

Comment: No. It has default 444 (r--r--r--) in my version. But still the owner can not read it.! It require sudo permissions.